# Adding Outlets to View Controller via Table View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, mono, xamarin

I'm attempting to create an application for iOS, using Xamarin and storyboards. Within this, there shall be a button located in a TableViewController which will navigate the user.

[image]

To do this, I've used a Container, embedded to a TableViewController. However, my concern is I wish to add an Outlet from the button within the TableViewController to the ViewController header class - Yet it only allows me to try and add one to the 'UITableViewController.h' file.

What is causing this and how am I able to add the Outlet to the 'ViewController.h' file? (Extremely sorry if this makes little sense)

Comment: This is not clear are you adding a button to each row of the table view controller? Why are you using a tableViewController and a ViewController? Should either or.

Comment: @Mikael - I've been using a TableViewController to style the button in a way I wish. It is included in a Static table cell. However, I wish to add an Outlet from that button to the main ViewController.h file.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use both the UITableViewController and the UIViewController. UITableViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController so all you need the UITableViewController and you should drag the outlet to it.